# Task notification email shows Due Date of "None"

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-activity

The OOTB Approval workflow sends task notifications to the CC line you specify when triggered from a workflow.

I've noticed in the email notification the Due By is None, even though I specify the due date when triggering the workflow.

[image: a]
How do I set this so it includes my List's Due Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found It.

1) In the Approval, click on "Change the behavior of the overall task process" 

2) Scroll down in the "When the Task Process Starts" step and look for the "Email Workflow Context:Initiator" action.

3) Click on the action to open the Define E-mail Message.

4) Change the Due By field to whatever date you prefer. For me, I used a date from the List Item that kicked off the workflow.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is quite disappointing that I have to crack open SPD for this, when it appears to be right there in the web-based "Change a Workflow" form where you spec the Duration Per Task and Duration Units. Sigh. And I give you a hearty +1 for the nice screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get it working with @April Drake's solution as I was kept on getting the Due Date as **None**. Upon further search, I stumble upon [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6452e868-39a9-41d8-9406-b77be8c621ec/sharpoint-2010-sp1-ootb-approval-workflow-missing-due-date?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) and the steps in it helped to generated the email with the correct due date. Posting it here just for reference as an alternative to the accepted answer.

The Steps to get the email to include the custom due date;

1) Edit the Approval Action in your workflow

2)Select "Change the behavior of a single task"

3) In the "When a Task is Pending" step, find and select "Current Task:AssignedTo"

4) Replace %Variable: DueDateOnly% by %Current Task:Due Date%

5) Voila!